# JSONObject com vários valores sem usar Array

Tags: java, android, json

### Objetivo

Criar um JSON com a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
    "auth": {
        "user": "rbz",
        "token": "abc123"
    }
}
```

---

### Cenário

Criando a estrutura raiz:

```
JSONObject JOraiz = new JSONObject();
```

Criando os valores `user` e `token`:

```
JSONObject JOauth_u = new JSONObject();
JSONObject JOauth_t = new JSONObject();
JOauth_u.put("user", "rbz");
JOauth_t.put("token", "abc123");
```

**Tentativa 1**

Utilizando `.put()`, o valor de `JOraiz` é **sobreescrito**:

```
JOraiz.put("auth", JOauth_u);
JOraiz.put("auth", JOauth_t);
```

*Saída*: `{"auth":{"token": "abc123"}}`

**Tentativa 2**

Utilizando `.acumulate()`, ele cria um **Array**:

```
JOraiz.accumulate("auth", JOauth_u);
JOraiz.accumulate("auth", JOauth_t);
```

*Saída*: `{"auth":[{"user": "rbz"},{"token": "abc123"}]}`

---

### Dúvida

- Como faço para ter 2 propriedades dentro de um mesmo objeto JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você consultar a [sintaxe do JSON](https://www.json.org/) verá que `{` e `}` delimitam um *object*, que nada mais é que um conjunto de pares chave/valor.

Agora, analisando o JSON que você quer criar:

```
{
    "auth": {
        "user": "rbz",
        "token": "abc123"
    }
}
```

Ele é um *object*, pois está delimitado por `{` e `}`. E ele contém uma chave `auth`, cujo valor é:

```
{
    "user": "rbz",
    "token": "abc123"
}
```

Ou seja, o valor da chave `auth` é outro *object* (pois também está delimitado por `{` e `}`), que por sua vez possui 2 pares de chave/valor:

- chave `user`, com valor `rbz`
- chave `token`, com valor `abc123`

Com isso, fica mais fácil saber como criar esta estrutura. Primeiro eu começo com o *object* mais interno - o que tem 2 pares de chave/valor (`user` e `token`):

```
// criar o object interno
JSONObject objectInterno = new JSONObject();
// adicionar os 2 pares chave/valor
objectInterno.put("user", "rbz");
objectInterno.put("token", "abc123");
```

E depois criamos o *object* principal, adicionando o *object* interno como valor da chave `auth`:

```
// criar o object principal
JSONObject principal = new JSONObject();
// adicionar object interno na chave "auth"
principal.put("auth", objectInterno);

System.out.println(principal.toString(4));
```

Assim, temos a estrutura desejada:

```
{"auth": {
    "user": "rbz",
    "token": "abc123"
}}
```

---

A sua primeira tentativa não funcionou porque [`put`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) sobrescreve o valor, caso já exista.

E a segunda tentativa não funciona porque [`accumulate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#accumulate(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) coloca os valores acumulados em um *array*. E além disso, você criou dois *objects* diferentes (um para o `user`, e outro para o `token`), o que não é necessário, já que ambos os valores estão no mesmo *object*.

Comment: Muito bom! Era o que eu precisava ter feito em minha resposta, mas você já fez até melhor! Acredito que o tópico irá ajudar bastante quem procura sobre `JSONObject`!

Comment: @rbz Pois é, muitos erros de JSON ocorrem pq a gente não presta atenção na estrutura e já sai escrevendo código, sendo que uns minutos para analisar antes podem nos poupar um bocado de tempo :-)

Comment: Exatamente. Se é um cara com pressa, já faz a gambiarra com `JSONArray`, depois pra tratar fica usando 3 níveis sem necessidade. É que meu "TOC" não me deixa fazer gambiarra assim! kkk

Answer (score 4):

Consegui, respondendo:

```
// Criando objeto JSON raiz
JSONObject JOraiz = new JSONObject();

// Criando objeto JSON auth
JSONObject JOauth = new JSONObject();

// Adicionando propriedades e valores ao objeto JOauth 
JOauth.put("user", "rbz");
JOauth.put("token", "abc123");

// Adicionando propriedades e valores ao objeto JOraiz
JOraiz.put("auth", JOauth);
```